# Algorithm / Library for measuring degree of equality of strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Is there an algorithm that given two strings yields the degree of equality between them, applying metrics that can be provided externally? For example, the two strings `"Plant code"` and `"PlantCode"` could be 0.8 equal, `"Plant code"` and `"Plant"` could be 0.6 equal, `"Truck no"` and `"shipment details"` could be 0.6 equal (using extrenally provided synonyms dictionary). The numbers are made up, but I hope they get the point across. Does there exist such an algorithm? I'd prefer if it comes as a library, rather than having to implement it on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but similar questions arose in (genome sequencing)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment]. These algorithms might give you inspiration, but won't help much with the dictionary case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Simmetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) library. It provides a whole number of simmilarity metrics.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) library can help: *This library implements Myer's diff algorithm which is generally considered to be the best general-purpose diff.*

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm and its example [java implementation](http://www.merriampark.com/ldjava.htm). It does not make it possible to provide an external metrics, though.

Comment: Based on this algorithm Apache Commons Lang provide another implementation. (http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%2)0java.lang.CharSequence%29