# How to simply check for the proximity of two words?

Tags: string-comparison, java

I want to check that 2 words are *very close* each others. My need is really simple: we allow the user to execute an action by answering to an email, and the user should answer with one word  (`APPROVED`, `REFUSED`, etc.). The list of possible action is really short. Now, I have to parse this answer, but my comparison has to be "*typo-safe*", i.e. if the user input is `aproved` or `apporved` for example, it should be ok.

Of course I can create my own *almost-ok* words (`["Approved", "Aproved", "Apporved", ...]`) and compare the user input with each element of this array, but defining all possible typos is really boring...

I know that I can do that with Lucene, but it seems a little bit too much for my needs, and ideally I would like to have a method like `WordUtils.proximity("Approved", userInput)`. In addition, a phonetical comparison is not mandatory in my case.

Is there a small library that can do that?

Comment: See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695532/algorithm-library-for-measuring-degree-of-equality-of-strings

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327513/fuzzy-string-search-in-java And more generally: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[java]%20%2blevenshtein%20%2blibrary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of the strings to indicate how close they are.

I guess there are more string distance algorithms but I used this before and it worked for me.

Here is an implementation you can try [Algorithm Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java)

Also, you can use [StringUtils#getLevenshteinDistance()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) from [Apache Commons-Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang)

Comment: [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) in Apache commons-lang has a utility method to calculate Levenshtein distances.

Comment: Cool! Thanks. In addition, Apache Common StringUtils provides a `getLevenshteinDistance()` method in v3!